# How to start horizontal scroll menu in centre

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to arrange a horizontal scrolling menu for a project where the middle button starts in the middle of the .scrollmenu div.

I'm currently using HTML and CSS, but am happy with options that include javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.container {
  width: 414px ;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:100px;
  border-weigth: 1px;
  border-color:white;
  border-style: solid;

 
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="">A</a>
  <a href="">B</a>
  <a href="">>!Middle!<</a>
  <a href="">D</a>
  <a href="">E</a>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript to start the scroll bar from center.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      let scrollElement = document.querySelector('.scrollmenu');
      scrollElement.scrollLeft =  (scrollElement.scrollWidth - 
      scrollElement.clientWidth ) / 2;
    });
```